# What percentage of Hindus belong to a sect that subscribes to the Vedanta school?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, sects, statistics

Indian schools of philosophy are traditionally divided into two categories, Astika and Nastika.  [Astika schools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%80stika_and_n%C4%81stika#.C4.80stika) accept the authority of the Vedas as divinely revealed truth (shruti), whereas [Nastika schools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%80stika_and_n%C4%81stika#N.C4.81stika), like Buddhism, Jainism, and Charvaka, reject the authority of the Vedas.  Generally members of Astika schools are the ones that are called Hindu, whereas the Nastika schools fall into the broader category of [Dharmic faiths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_religions#.22Dharmic_religions.22).  In any case, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_philosophy) are the traditional Astika schools of philosophy:

1. Samkhya
2. Yoga
3. Nyaya
4. Vaisheshika
5. Mimāṃsā
6. Vedanta

But it seems to me that one school is vastly more popular than the others: the [Vedanta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedanta) school, which derives its tenets from the philosophical teachings of the Upanishads, as expounded in Vyasa's [Brahma Sutras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahma_Sutras).  [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedanta#Schools_of_Vedanta) is Wikipedia's chart of the various Vedanta philosophies:

[image]

From what I can tell, almost every popular sect of Hinduism subscribes to one of these Vedanta philosophies.  Smarthas, for instance, believe in Adi Shankarachatya's philosophy of Advaita Vedanta, according to which Jivatma (the individual soul) and Paramatma (divine soul or supersoul) are identical.  Sri Vaishnavas believe in Ramanujacharya's philosophy of Visistadvaita Vedanta, according to which Jivatmas are distinct parts of Parmatma but Paramatma extends beyond them.  And Gaudiya Vaishnavas believe in Chaitanya Mahaprabhu's Vedantic philosophy of Achintya Bheda Abheda, according to which there is a simultaneous unity and difference between Jivatma and Paramatma that is inconceivable.

So my question is, what is the percentage of Hindus who belong to a sect which subscribes to the Vedanta school of philosophy?  Note that when I say "Hindu" I don't mean Buddhists and the like, I just mean people belonging to the Astika schools.  I'm wondering how many Hindus belong to the Vedanta school, compared to how many Hindus belong to the other Astika schools like Purva Mimamsa.

My guess is that the percentage is significantly greater than 95%, but have there been any statistics collected on this?

Comment: are you looking for a scriptural statistic (as in like is it mentioned somewhere in scripture how many % of Hindus are vedantic)? or an opinion? Or perhaps a poll in StackExchange hehe :)

Comment: @Sai Haha no, I'm not looking for something in scripture.  I'm looking for modern statistics of how many Hindus currently belong to sects that follow Vedanta.  People conduct statistical studies on religions all the time, like how many Muslims are Sunni vs. Shia, how many Christians are Catholics vs. Protestant, etc.

Comment: oh I see. :) Not sure if there would be a statistic because unlike the other sects I believe that the sects in Hinduism are not really conflicting, but one can choose to follow several of these together.

Comment: @Sai Well, you can worship both Vishnu and Shiva, but people don't generally identify themselves as both Sri Vaishnavas and Smarthas, for instance.  So it would certainly be possible to collect statistics on the sect that people self-identify as.

Comment: perhaps (and Im not saying that it is not :D)  not in the way you mentioned. But I could certainly call myself both a Yogi (focusses on conentration and meditation) and a Vedanti (focusses on inner meaning of scriptures). I could also be both a Vaisheshikist (hehe) (one who believes in scientific experimentation) as well as Nyay-ist (hehe) ( believes in logical reasoning). Perhaps within those schools of thought there may  be some conflicting beliefs. Just my opinion

Comment: @Sai Haha, yeah if you just look at the names of the different philosophical schools, you might even think that you belong to all six.  But those names are deceptive: to be a Vedantin, for instance, doesn't mean you like to study the meaning of the Vedas, it means that you believe in the specific doctrines Vyasa lays out in the Brahma Sutras: http://www.advaita.it/library/brahmasutras2.htm The other schools also have very detailed belief systems.  So just because you value or focus on logic and empirical work doesn't mean anything.  These are schools of philosophy, not ways of life.

Comment: @Sai I think you may be confusing schools of Hindu philosophy with the paths a Hindu can take, like Karma Yoga, Bhakti Yoga, Jnana Yoga, etc.

Comment: Well alright, accepted. But in my opinion when you said 'to be a Vedantin, for instance, it means that you believe in the specific doctrines Vyasa lays out in the Brahma Sutras' I think that's a specific definition that you subscribe to of what a Vedanti is. Whereas I am talking about how I would call myself a Vedanti, because I believe in a different definition what it takes to be a Vedanti. Therefore different people (who would admittedly follow different vedantic beliefs) would still consider themselves vedantic.

Comment: I am already getting 'Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat' stuffs. So I would like to end it here by saying perhaps if you would be able to define what exactly in your question you expect when you say 'Nyaya' or 'Yoga' then it would help narrow down and possibly easier to answer :). All the best!

Comment: @Sai Yeah, I could provide definitions for the different schools.  But in any case, I'm not asking about how many Hindus would self-identify as Vedanta, because most people haven't even heard of the word "Vedanta".  Rather, I'm asking how many people belong to a sect of Hinduism which subscribes to Vedanta.  People would presumably know if they're Sri Vaishnava or Smartha, for instance, and based on that you can place them in one of the six Astika schools.  So all I really want is a breakdown of Hindus by sect, not by philosophy, and then a breakdown by philosophy can be inferred.

Comment: Okay so basically you're asking this: "If you are a Sri Vaishnava, you're categorized as Vedantic cuz that's what it subscribes to" and "If you are at Iskcon let me know and I'll categorize you as Vedantic cuz that's what it's based off". I get it. But I think it could be clearer that that's what you want from the question (question just says "what percentage of hindus belong to vedanta school"). In any case I have understood now what exactly you require :). Thanks for taking the time to clarify things!

Comment: Of the discussion, I think many Hindus subscribe to many things together. When they self-identify, they would self-identify multiply. They can go to a temple, attend a Vedanta class, do puja in the morning clean the beach in the evening and meditate on the Self in the night. Most modern masters, Aurobindo, Vivekanand etc  have advocated a synthesis of multiple streams and the "exclusive self-identifying"  people, such as this and not that, will be very few. This would require a survey, that uses checkboxes with multiple select, not a combo box, LoL. A clear divide is unlikely to be found.

Comment: Most of the people don't even know the names of the Astika schools let alone subscribing to them. "My guess is that the percentage is significantly greater than 95%" It is not even close to that. The percentage is less than 5%, that also I think is way too much. The real figure is in the range of 0.45% to 0.75%. Of course, this is all speculation but I strongly believe this is the correct figure.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Please see my conversation with Sai above. Im not asking how many people would say that they belong to the Vedanta school if you asked them. I'm asking, if you asked people what sect of Hinduism they belonged to, and then you classify those people according to what Astika school their sect believes in, then what is the percentage of people that would be classified under the Vedanta school? That's the question whose answer I think is far greater than 95%. Like Sri Vaishnavas, Advaitins, Madhvas, Gaudiya Vaishnavas, Ramanandis, etc. all belong to sects which subscribe to Vedanta

Comment: Now all are nastika schools only due to kaliyuga.

Comment: Limiting the denotation of vedanta to uttara mimamsa is unwelcome. Vedanta has the meaning of "culmination of gnyana". In this light, this Q is incorrect. Plus the darsanas are not -isms.

Comment: @moonstar Well, Vedanta has multiple meanings.  It can denote the Upanishads, it can denote a Darshana, and it can denote the culmination of Jnana.  This question of mine is about the Vedanta Darshana, aka the Uttara Mimamsa Darshana.  And I would say that the Darshana's are isms.  They are schools of philosophy with distinct sets of beliefs, and they each come with a set of philosophers who try to disprove all the other Darshanas.  That sounds like an ism to me.

Comment: If the question is about uttara mimasa, state so. Do not use the collective noun of vedanta.

Comment: @moonstar By saying the term "Vedanta school", I make clear that I'm talking about the Darshana.

Comment: Its not clear. Especially not  to the average reader.

Comment: @moonstar Well, I specifically list the 6 Astika schools and then ask about the Vedanta school.

Comment: That's not sufficient. Its not even straightforward.  And darsanas are not isms. To say logic is an ism is vitanDa vAda

Comment: @moonstar In what sense are Darshanas not isms?  They are distinct belief systems.  What else is an "ism"?

Comment: I already gave an example as to why they are not isms. Darsanas are not ideologies. This Q is impossible to answer because noone keeps such a census . the Q is designed to farm reputation and get bumped up continually by the community user

Comment: @moonstar Sorry, what was the example you gave to show they are not ideologies?  I must have missed it.  Was "logic", i.e. Nyaya, your example? But the Nyaya Darshana is different from just logic. The Nyaya Darshana had very specific philosophical beliefs; for instance, they believed that God is only the efficient cause of the Universe, in contrast to the Vedanta Darshana which says that Brahman is both the efficient cause and the material cause. That's why the Advaita philosopher Sri Harsha wrote a refutation of the Nyaya Darshana, the Khandana Khanda Khadya. Vyasa does so too in Brahmasutras

Comment: @moonstar I don't think this question is impossible to answer.  I agree that people wouldn't compile stats on different Astika Darshanas, but they might keep stats on how many members different sects of Hinduism belong to, and then by seeing what Darshanas these sects of Hinduism subscribe to, one can infer the answer to my question.  For instance, Sri Vaishnavas subscribe to the Vedanta Darshana, whereas Kashmiri Shaivites do not.  And this question isn't designed to farm reputation, I'm genuinely interested in the answer. I think the answer is "the vast majority", but I want to know how big.

Comment: 1) Nyaya is logic and epistemology.  Harsha's work AFAIK criticises nyaya's methodologies of knowledge acquisition. It was also later refuted and we have a navyanyaya theory as well. 2) Noone keeps those numbers. Roundabout attempts to bring some obscure connection between existing sects (whose censuses are a novelty I see only in this Q) and darsanas is far-fetched at best

Comment: @moonstar Nyaya is not just logic and epistemology.  The different Darshanas all have their own epistemology and ontology.  The Vaisheshika school believes in two Pramanas, Samkhya, Yoga, and Vedanta (mostly) believe in three, Nyaya believes in four, Prabhakaras in five, Bhattas and Advaitins in six.  The different Darshanas also differ on the material cause of the Universe, the issue of whether Atma is atomic or omnipresent, the way to prove the existence of God, etc.  There is a reason why Vyasa refutes all the other Darshanas in Adhyaya 2 Pada 2 of the Brahma Sutras.

Answer (score 5):

If the question is about Hinduism at present, then I think it is faulty. Of the six Astika schools—Sankya, Yoga, Nyaya, Vaisheshika, Mimangsha, Vedanta, each which differed a little bit in their philosophy—are all dead except the Vedanta. Hence, Upanishad means Vedanta now. Later, various philosophies emerged from Vedanta, namely Advaita, Bishista advaita, Dvaita, Suddha advaita, Dvaita advaita, and Achinta Veda Aveda.

This later gave rise to present sects like Shaivas, Vaishnavas, Shaktas, Smartas, Vedics (who don't use effigies), and devotees of other Gods or Avtaars.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! I have taken the liberty of editing your answer to enhance its readability. In future, please be sure to add spaces after periods (.) and commas (,). Also, as we want to make sure we have top-notch answers, please reference your sources.

Answer (score 4):

There is a different way of classification within Asktika i.e. those who accept the authority of vedas.

Astikas can be classified into 2 groups:

1. **Vedanta / YogaVedanta**, all the schools (including vedanta) mentioned in the question above fall under this category.
2. **VedaAgama / Agama**: ShaivaAgamas(Shiva), ViashnAgamas(Vishnu), ShaktAgamas(Shakti) (maybe more) are different traditions under this category. Each of these agamas have numerous different sub-branches and philosophies.

The primary difference between the 2 schools is the scope / role played by Guru.

In all vendanta based traditions reading/learning from text is sufficient. An acharya or Guru is a force multiplier or a mentor but ***not essential***.

On the other hard in Agama based tradition initiation by ***enlightened Guru is essential***. And they prescribe a very specific lifestyle and rituals for individuals and communities. For eg temples are central to Agamic lifestyle.

**From the point of view of Agamas, Vedas are as "pure science" and Agama are "applied technology"**

Majority of hindus, gurus and priests follow some vedanta/YogaVedanta tradition. Many priests whose earlier generations were practitioners of Agamic tradition now follow a vedantic tradition.
***Agamic traditions are harder to follow*** as it calls for specific "actions" to be performed which is much tougher to follow.

***PS***: the wikipedia gives an impression of Agamas vs vedas which is incorrect.

***PPS***: NeoVedanta school being started by Sri RamaKrishna and Swami Vivekananda is "incorrect" at best.

***PPS***: When AdiShankara when up to Kashmir from Kerala he was a vendatin but was initiated into Agamas by AbhinavGupta in Kashmir. Since then his discourses was based on Agamas (which also consider Vedas as supreme)

Comment: I did not get about neo-advaita, where and what is incorrect.

Comment: NeoVedanta is attributed to SriRamaKrishna and SwamiVivekananda ... neo-vedanta is a mis-appropriated / decontextualized version of their teachings created much later by certain groups ... You can read "IndrasNet" by Rajiv Malhotra to understand it further

Comment: You should cite some sources.

Comment: @Pandya most of the Hindu literature is not digitized, its a massive problem. The knowledge is passed on in the traditional way or via Gurus

Comment: @Akhil when you say "NeoVedanta school being started by Sri RamaKrishna and Swami Vivekananda is "incorrect" at best." do you mean calling the philosophy of Shri Ramakrishna and Swami Vivekananda "NeoVedanta" is wrong rather the concept propounded by them. Please do make this careful distinction as there is a possibility of people assuming that you are accusing the philosophy of Ramakrishna mission as wrong instead of the nomenclature of it.

Answer (score 2):

It is my understanding that Karma Kanda and Upasana Kanda are portions of Vedas where there is identity with specific Ishta Devata. In Vedanta the identity shifts to nature of self in this there are various schools of philosophy where in duality , monism etc are discussed as the nature of Self. So there cannot be a connection between shan-Matha and Vedanta

Comment: Welcome! Answers on this site should be backed up with sources. Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)