# Hindu demographics in Indonesia

Tags: statistics

I'm looking for Demographic data of Hindu population in Indonesia since the 1940's. A timeseries of % of Hindu population there would be ideal.

Comment: i am not sure whether this question would fit for this site.

Comment: Well, I assumed that since this stackexchange forum is named 'Hinduism' it concerns all Hindu affairs and not just philosophy. spirituality, and religion.

Comment: I think questions asking for statistics related to Hinduism are fine; I've asked one myself: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3193/36