# What herbs found on Earth give magical powers?

Tags: yoga, siddhi, plants, yoga-sutras

As I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3193/36), by far the most popular school of Hindu philosophy is the Vedanta school. But there are five other Astika or orthodox schools of Hindu philosophy: Purva Mimamsa, Samkhya, Yoga, Vaisheshika, and Nyaya.  My question is about the Yoga school, which had a similar worldview to the Samkhya school except it embraced the existence of a supreme being.  The defining text of the Yoga school is Patanjali's Yoga Sutras.

Now one of the tenets of the Yoga school is that you can obtain Siddhis or magical powers through meditation.  But that's not the only way to obtain Siddhis, as Patanjali describes in [Adhyaya 4 Sutra 1](https://www.ashtangayoga.info/philosophy/yoga-sutra/chapter-4/item/janma-sadhi-mantra-tapas-samaadhi-siddhaya/) of the Yoga Sutras:

> janma-**oṣadhi**-mantra-tapas-samādhi-jāḥ siddhayaḥ
>
> Supernatural powers (siddhis) arise from birth, **drugs**, mantras, austerity, or yoga (samadhi)

As you can see, one of the methods of obtaining Siddhis is through the use of drugs or herbs.  Here is what the Advaita philosopher Vachaspati Mishra says in [this excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyJ0l.jpg) from his commentary on the Yoga Sutra:

> He describes the attainments [Siddhis] due to drugs: - "In the houses of the Asuras."  Man passes to the places of the Asuras for some reason.  He is met there by lovely Asura damsels, and is given an offering of elixer.  Using that he comes to possess the attainments of freedom from decay and death, and other attainments.  **Or, the same may take place even here by the use of elixir, as in the case of the thinker Mandavya, who resided in the Vindhya mountains and who used the elixir.**

Now it would obviously be impractical to go to Patalaloka and obtain herbs from Asura damsels.  But I'm interested in the part in bold, where Vachaspati Mishra claims that you can obtain Siddhis using herbs right here on Earth.  So my question is, what herbs available on Earth grant Siddhis?

Do any scriptures shed light on this?  What was the elixir used by sage Mandavya, for instance?

Comment: do you feel vedanta is more popular than yoga

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Yes, in the sense that almost all Hindus today belong to a sect of Hinduism that subscribes to the Vedanta school.  Now it's certainly true that the word Yoga is more popular than the word Vedanta, but the number of people who actually subscribe to the philosophical tenets of Patanjali's Yoga school is relatively small.

Comment: but yoga is more practical in nature than theory ..

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Yeah, a lot of Advaitins, especially after the time of Vivekananda, utilize the methods of Ashtanga Yoga.

Comment: Sri M's guru Sri Maheswarnath Babaji made him drink Soma rasa which was required to quickly awaken Kundalini.

Comment: not sure about ancient drugs, but common ones like ganja/LSD can make you achieve superhuman concentration, hear minute sounds, and see visions.

Comment: @ram Yeah, but I'm interested in the specific Siddhis described in the Yoga Sutras, which are things like shrinking to minuscule size, instantaneously teleporting from one place to another, etc.

Comment: Although some of the philosophical conclusions reached by Patanjali have been rejected by Vedantists, the practices outlined by him have been adapted by Vedantists. I have always thought that it was not so much the attainment of siddhis that can be attained by the indigestion of certain drugs, but rather a heightened state of consciousness. Unfortunately the state attained is not permanent and the wearing off of the effects of the drugs on the mind brings the mind down sometimes into a more tamasic state.

Comment: I think we should be more circumspect about asking questions such as  "how to get magical powers". They may cause more harm than not.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Well, I certainly agree that the pursuit of magical powers is detrimental insofar as it distracts from higher goals like Moksha.  And the actual obtaining of magical powers is even more dangerous.  But I'm not trying to get magical powers, I'm just asking this question out of intellectual curiosity.  In any case, considering that Adi Shankaracharya saw fit to address this subject in his Yoga Sutra Vivarana, I don't think there's much harm in posting a question about this subject.

Comment: I understand you are not trying to gain magical powers. however, there may be a stray user that may pursue their obtainment based on the question and answer. this happens when people do not understand the larger aspects of yoga, siddhi, laws of the universe, maintaining balance, upsetting the natural karma etc. FYI - those who provide religious discourse and demystification are forbidden from discussing such matters openly in sabhas. The same rules should be followed on open fora such as this.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in [this excerpt](https://books.google.com/books/content?id=C8LWAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA366&img=1&pgis=1&dq=Amalaka&sig=ACfU3U0vtV6C1RlRZB4UMqxnpAhTZF9UaQ&edge=0) from Adi Shankaracharya's commentary on the Yoga Sutras:

> dehāntaritā yathā yogādinā dehāntareṣu svargādiṣu janmasiddhiḥ. oṣadhibhir asurabhavaneṣu *rasāyanena somāmala- kādibhakṣaṇena** pūrvadehānapanayenaiva
>
> "The perfections from birth are in a different body", being attainment of another body in heaven or similar region, by yoga or other means. "From drugs - such as the elixir of the demon realms": here the original body is not discarded, but by taking **drugs such as Soma or the Amalaka plant** (some perfection [Siddhi] is attained)

Now the Soma plant is notoriously hard to identify, although scholars today think it's most likely the [Ephedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephedra_(plant)) plant.  But the identity of Amalaka is well-known; it's the [Indian gooseberry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phyllanthus_emblica).

And indeed, Rasayana made from Amalaka, which is what Adi Shankaracharya is talking about, is a well-known Ayurvedic medicine; see page 32 of [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=ekjtVOppIxwC&lpg=PA32&dq=amalaka%20rasayana&pg=PA32#v=onepage&q&f=false), which says that the effect is "to transform old men into young, with new hair and teeth, and induce physical power like that of an elephant."  That sounds like a Siddhi to me.

Comment: its not exactly siddhi but even now the amalaki rasayana is available you can also make it. its just like anti ageing or antioxidant. not exactly magical .

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Well, Adi Shankaracharya seems to think that the Amalaka plant grants Siddhis.  I may post a follow-up question on that.

Comment: You can go through clinical trials on the fruit and find yourself. however there are herbs i will post once i get some references.

Comment: Several rasayanas are there in ayurveda.. different rasayanas are meant to be consumed in different seasons like one in grishma , another in vasanta, etc..they simply are like rejuvenator..consuming them does not give one magical powers or siddhis..

Comment: @Rickross Well, there must be a reason that Adi Shankaracharya says that the Amalaka plant gives Siddhis.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Are you still planning to post an answer?

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for specific 'siddhis', realize that those ancient authors may have been exaggerating or speaking metaphorically, in terms of the astral/ethereal body and not the physical body. However, I've come to learn the following herbs do give some 'special powers'. These gifts can be obtained through intense meditation, so herbs aren't strictly necessary, but they provide a 'shortcut', like steroids do for athletes.

- kanna - This makes me more sensitive to pranna/chi/qi and I can feel energy fields of people and crystals with my hands, and direct energy as well. The chakras become very sensitive, and kanna especially works to open up the heart chakra. https://examine.com/supplements/sceletium-tortuosum/
- sativa - This also makes one more sensitive to energy, however it often has unpleasant side effects like dry mouth, dry eyes, or paranoia.
- LSD - not really a plant, but it does exist in nature. This seems to improve your reaction time and concentration in micro doses. Anything that requires rhythmic movement becomes magically easier as time seems to slow down during concentration. This one may fit "Mahima: expanding one's body to an infinitely large size". I've experienced this while on LSD and staring at the full moon and holding a quartz crystal. It felt like my presence extended up towards the top of the clouds.
- ayahuasca - This may fit "Laghima: becoming almost weightless" or "Prāpti: having unrestricted access to all places" from what I've read, as you experience relaxation and visions which may be a form of astral travel. I've not tried this.

Comment: I'm interested in what Hindu scripture says, not what scientific research says or what your personal experience with illegal drugs says.