# Did the Purva Mimamsa school think the Devas have no intelligence?

Tags: philosophy, purva-mimamsa, gods, nyaya

Udayana's Nyaya Kusumanjali is a Nyaya-Vaisheshika work which seeks to logically prove the existence of God. In [this excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQU7i.jpg) from the Nyaya Kusumanjali, Udayana describes how the Prana Pratishtha ritual makes the presence of a Deva enter a statue:

> The deities become conciliated in the ceremonies of consecration, and show it by coming to take up their residence, i.e. by the appropriation of the image and self-consciousness thereto; but by the touch of an impure person such appropriation and self-consciousness are rendered void.  Even on **the Mimansaka view which disputes the intelligence of the deities**, we can say that it is the idea that the worship has been performed in a due manner, and that the image has been duly consecrated, - this idea also being necessarily accompanied by the absence of the touch of any impure person, - which constitutes the image's fitness as an object of worship, and the ceremony's importance lies in its contributing to produce the idea

I asked about the "impure person" part in my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21299/36), but now I'm interested in the part in bold.  My question is, is it true that the Purva Mimamsa school believed that the Devas had no intelligence, i.e. no capacity to think?

Now as I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21116/36), the Purva Mimamsa school believed a lot a strange things about the Devas: that they don't have bodies, that they do not consume offerings made in Yagnas, that they're not allowed to do Yagnas themselves, and that the only role they play in Yagnas is that offerings are made with reference to them as recipients.  And in [this excerpt](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21116/36) from his commentary on the Purva Mimamsa Sutras, Shabaraswami says that it would not hurt the Purva Mimamsa position if someone said that the Devas are just words:

> Says the Opponent - "In that case it is the word that becomes the Deity." Answer - This is an idea that it is not for us to refute; because such an idea, if expressed, does not militate against our view; on the contrary it lends all the more strength to the view [that different names of the same Deva should not be substituted for one another].

But are there any Purva Mimamsa works which say that the Devas have no intelligence?

Comment: Devas surely has intelligent and proof of this can be found in BG. In starting of BG it is started that knowledge of Geeta was first of all given to Sun God by Lord Vishnu himself. And it is the Sun God who was Guru of Lord Hanuman. This doesn't proves extreme knowledge of devas? Besides how a knowledge less person can be the King of Devas(Indra)? It's baseless thoughts that devas don't have any intelligence.

Comment: @Rishabh Yeah, the Devas definitely have intelligence.  But the Purva Mimamsa school had very strange beliefs.  They rejected all factual information given in Hindu scripture; they thought Hindu scripture was only authoritative concerning what actions you should do.  See my answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21116/36 They thought that all factual statements in Hindu scripture were just ways of encouraging people to do the actions prescribed.  They didn't even think the Mahabharata war ever took place!

Comment: I think the statement by Udayana that *"the Mimansaka view which disputes the intelligence of the deities"* is basically his way of saying that the Mimansakas don't necessarily support the corporeality of the Devas, and since Mimansakas view the Devas as existing at least by their linguistic word, here also he says that according to that view, the Deva exists within the idol as long as the *idea* of it's existence is there, meaning as long as the Prana Pratishtha ritual is done with the intention of consecrating the Deva in the idol.