# Sub-castes within lingayatism?

Tags: culture, caste-system

Are the sub-castes within lingayatism similar to the hindu caste system like the Sharana/Ainor(priests), Shettar(merchants/vaishyas), holeya(shudra) etc ?

---

NOTE: What will be the accepted references for this answer?
Answer: Actually, Sikh scriptures also explicitly deny casteism "- but finally practically they do have khatri etc lots of caste and caste discrimination  prevalent in them https://www.quora.com/Who-is-better-and-why-Jatt-sikhs-or-Bhapa-sikhs/answer/Kunal-Kakkar-1 .
 In the same way, in the above question asks that - "although lingayats scripture says that there is no caste, **is it true that on practical world lingayats are having the same rigid caste system prevalent in them too, even if their scriptures do not sanction it?** " . **Hence,** not just the scriptures, BUT **ALSO newspaper reports, govt. reports and normal article links about prevalent castes -will also constitute valid reference for the answers.**

Comment: What language is shettar, holeya etc?

Comment: @Rickross It is Kannada

Comment: Yes there are many Jatis within Lingayats

Comment: @Akhil, can you please kindly elaborate your answer. Please also check the note in above question, about what additional sources will constitute valid references for the answer.

Comment: @zaxebo1 I wrote a comment instead of answer for this reason, the use  of the word "caste" is wrong read my answer at https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26681/are-there-finer-classifications-than-the-4-varna-guna-classification-in-scriptur/26684#26684

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, **NO.** They don't have sub-castes/verna system as Hinduism. Ultimately their aim was to overcome the differentiation of people based on verna, creed, class and sex and to treat all people equally.

I can quote few references:

From [this link](http://lingayatreligion.com/LIngayatGlance.htm)

> Aim of Lingayat Religion: Equality without any distinction of caste, creed, class or sex. To build up a welfare state free from caste, creed, class and based on religious values.

Also from [this link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Lingayat)

> a member of a Saiva sect of southern India marked by wearing of the lingam and characterized by denial of caste distinctions

Also from Wikipedia:

> Lingayatism is often considered a Hindu sect,[7][6][web 1][note 4] because it shares beliefs with Indian religions,[6][8][note 5] and "their [Lingayats] beliefs are syncretistic and include an assemblage of many Hindu elements, including the name of their god, Shiva, who is one of the chief figures of the Hindu pantheon."[6] Yet, Lingayatism also "makes several departures from mainstream Hinduism,"[8] and rejects the authority of the Vedas, the caste system and the Hindu concepts of reincarnation and karma.[8] Its worship is centred on Hindu god Shiva as the universal god in the iconographic form of Ishtalinga.[1](http://lingayatreligion.com/LIngayatGlance.htm)[note 6] They believe that they will be reunited with Shiva after their death by wearing the lingam.[40]

As you can see various references clearly says, Lingayatism rejects any differentiation based on caste, creed, sex etc. So, they don't have any caste etc. Which was not the aim of Guru Basavanna. Even if you see people claim they have casteism, then it's ultimately defeats the purpose of Basavanna's moment ie society without discrimination based on caste, color, sex etc.

Comment: Actually, Sikh scriptures also explcitly deny casteism "- but finally **practically** they do have khatri etc lots of caste and caste discrimination https://www.quora.com/Who-is-better-and-why-Jatt-sikhs-or-Bhapa-sikhs/answer/Kunal-Kakkar-1   . In the same way, in the above question asks that  - "although lingayats scripture says that there is no caste, is it true that on practical world lingayats are having the same rigid caste system?"