# Were Caṇḍālas untouchables purely because they disposed corpses?

Tags: health, untouchability, chandala

I have seen certain traditionalists on social media often suggest that Caṇḍālas may have been simply treated as untouchables because they disposed corpses which presented a health risk to other members of the society at large.

Do any Hindu Śāstras explicitly justify the untouchability of Caṇḍālas on such grounds of public health?

Comment: Health aspect Not explicitly specified in the dharmashastras, but. Please note: death in the family and touching dead bodies leads to ritual impurity. If you touch someone (even non Chandala) during ashaucha, then you must have a bath. Chandalas are permanently engaged in such activity and hence a bath is recommended to regain ritual purity. During olden times, people used to gift gold and silver to them, for tending to the bodies of dead relatives. For gold silver you can refer the video [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44070/lord-shiva-s-curse-and-the-origin-of-chandalas)

Comment: @Archit But were Caṇḍālas considered touchable after bathing?

Comment: @Ramadasa not them but non chandala. Non chandala were touchable after bathing. For chandala they would be all the time engaged in death only, living in the crematorium so even if they have a bath and come they’re still in the crematorium precincts, and repeated tending would cause ashaucha for longer. So it’s tough to say. But in my opinion if they wait for sometime say ten days to a month and don’t go back to the crematorium, then there should be no reason to consider them ‘untouchable.’

Comment: @Archit sounds logical.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt the claim that Chandalas were untouchables because they handled corpses. The more plausible reason is that they were considered as sinners.

**Contact with a sinner**

> **The sin resulting from contact with the sinner** is equal to the sin of
> the original sinner. Still by repeating the mantra ten thousand times
> he is liberated from sin.

**Linga Purana I.15.14**

The word Chandala was used to signify a sinner. Hence he cannot be touched for fear of contracting sin. However, the redeeming feature was that in the Upanishads a person was called a Chandala if his conduct was bad.

> Those whose conduct here has been good will quickly attain a good
> birth (literally womb), the birth of a brahmin, the birth of a
> Ksatriya or the birth of a Vaisya. **But those whose conduct here has
> been evil,** will quickly attain an evil birth, the birth of a dog, the
> birth of a hog or the birth of a **chandala**.

**Chandogya Upanishad V.10.7**

However, as the Varna system died and the caste system became popular the definition changed. Chandala was now defined as a person born of a Sudra father and a Brahmana mother. So conduct played no role in designating a person a Chandala. He is by definition a sinner regardless of his conduct. Hence he cannot be touched whatever he may do.

The Linga Purana shloka was a loaded gun. At least it was pointed at a sinner as long as the Varna system was working. Once the definition of a Chandala was changed the gun was pointed at a whole class of people designated as a Chandala without rhyme or reason.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't see Chandala as being used for sinner (or vice cersa) as per your references.