# What does a Dove symbolize?

Tags: symbolism

In Christianity a dove symbolizes peace.

Does it have a similar meaning in Hinduism if any meaning at all?

Comment: I don't think Dove symbolism of peace is specific to Christianity. It is a universal symbol of peace.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma well what verses talk about then?  Maybe I should edit the question.

Comment: As per few Puranas (*Vayu Purana*, *Linga Purana* and *Markandeya Purana*), if a dove alights on one's head, that is a reason for sorrow. That means that person may die within few months if the effect is not minimized - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/23260/12304 .. So Dove symbolize peace..I mean Rest in Peace... :P

Comment: @YDS you are welcome to post that as an answer on a side note I don't see that cited in your page anywhere.

Comment: Actually it's cited in the linked question..u can also check it here as well https://archive.org/stream/VayuPurana.Vol.1/Vayu%20Purana.%20Vol.%201#page/n176/mode/1up/search/subject%3A%22Vayu+Purana%22 and http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/lingapurana/bookview.php?chapnum=16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering only this part of your question

> Does a dove have any meaning at all in Hinduism?

As per  [of Vayu Purana - CHAPTER NINETEEN : Evil Omen Foreboding Death](https://archive.org/stream/VayuPurana.Vol.1/Vayu%20Purana.%20Vol.%201#page/n176/mode/1up/search/subject%3A%22Vayu+Purana%22)

> [Vayu said:]
>
> 6. If a crow, a **dove**, a vulture or any other bird of prey settles on his head, he does not survive six months.

---

Related Question

[How do you know death is near for a person as per scriptures? Is there any reference?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23268/12304)