# Is there any significance of flying Eagle touching head?

Tags: scripture, sin, superstitions, pitru, omens

Today an eagle touched my head while I was in my open terrace. For last few days it was flying very near to me.

In various chapters of Mahabharata, there are instances of signs provided by animals. Incidentally in internet, I also saw various discussions of Eagle touching heads. Usually we may think that [probably old] eagle might be considering us a source of food, until coming near.

Is there any extra significance of Eagle touching head?
(e.g. good/bad omen, *pitru vidhi* is due, ...)

---

> Opinions on this bird differ across the world. In the west, it's seen as a sign of enemity, but in the east, thanks to the Garuda connection, sighting one in the sky is considered a sign of hope...I remember my grandmother always keeping her eyes peeled to spot one in the distant sky... [[source]](https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.speakingtree.in/allslides/lucky-and-unlucky-omens-what-birds-and-animals-tell-us/m-lite)

Comment: This is interesting. But normally eagles don't come to that low heights isn't it? Anyways Pitrus may not be related here because normally crows are associated with them.. But a vulture (Gridha) is associated with Shani Deva. But vulture and eagles are probably different.

Comment: Eagle is bird of prey right? If so its bad omen.. - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23268/12304

Comment: @iammilind It's not a bad omen, it's a good sign, something good is coming your way in the near future. I'm not saying this for the heck of saying it but am saying this out of personal experience, I was touched by eagle multiple times and believe me in few weeks got a really good news!

Comment: @JustDoIt, thanks. Hoping for the same. Other references seem fearful. :-)

Comment: The significance is to make sure you don't have any head injuries, and if you do, get it disinfected.

Answer (score 2):

From 2 answers mentioned in below thread, it appears to be a bad omen! So time to be careful!
[How do you know death is near for a person as per scriptures? Is there any reference?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/23260/1049)

> VAyu PurAna
>   5. He whose feet crack either in the front or the back, or becomes dust or marshy, lives only for seven months  <sub>(I have backfoot cracks for several years)</sub>
>   6. If a crow, a dove, a vulture or any other bird of prey settles on his head, he doesn't survive for six months <sub>(in my case, it touched; need to check Sanskrit translation, if it's "settle" or "touch")</sub>

Similar verse from another answer in same thread:

> a dream of a crow, or a kite or dove or any other meat-eating bird on a person’s head might presume death within six months

I didn't have dream. But just in case if someone is dreaming me in my real time :-) (i.e. [Inception movie](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception) style).

Comment: Well I was touch few times and that too in the year 2014 and am still alive in 2018, so it's not a bad omen but in fact I got two really good news :)