# Is it a bad omen to see snakes chasing you in dreams?

Tags: dream, omens

Is it a bad omen to see snakes trying to chase you in dreams? What do scriptures say about such dreams? If its a bad omen, what is the remedy for it?

Comment: Related: [Is there any significance of flying Eagle touching head?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/23622/1049).

Comment: Every culture has its own interpretation about dreams,. there is no dream without your own reaction in the dream.

Comment: ash, **snakes/serpents** (bhujang is the exact word in Sanskrit shloka) and dried rivers in the dream is a bad omen.. - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23268/12304 (point 16)...further point 33 to 40 describe about minimising the effect of bad omens..

Comment: Snakes chasing you is something bad, given if you have not read about Snakes/Nagas before sleep. Check your kundali and see if you have Kala Sarpa dosham. It could be a sign too.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Actually my parents dreamt about snakes on the same night. My Mom was being chased by snakes whereas my Dad vaguely remembers the incident.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per [this Agni Purana chapter](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/agni/bookview.php?chapnum=14), it is a good omen in fact.

> A fairly detailed analysis of dreams and Omens is provided in Agni
>   Purana. **Dreams are good when they involve mountains, palaces, snakes**,
>   riding horses or bulls, white flowers, trees, possession of arms and
>   many heads, triumphs in wars, wearing garlands or clothes, witnessing
>   eclipses, Stars, Sun or Moon, eating rice pudding, drinking wine or
>   blood, eating meat,milking cows, buffalos, blessings from Devas,
>   Brahmanas, coronation, one’s own death or cutting off head, one’s own
>   house burning, playing musical instruments, climbing trees, clear
>   skies, wet clothes and so on. Bad dreams are a shaven head of one’s
>   own, wearing shabby clothes, drinking oil, house collapse, angry Gods
>   or Brahmanas, falling from above, killing snakes or animals, playing
>   with monkeys, weddings, singing and so on.  Prayers to Vishnu, or
>   Shiva or Ganesha or Surya would appease bad dreams, while good dreams
>   should enable the dreamer to make them true if the person discontinues
>   sleeping.

The ["Essence of Dharma Sindhu"](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/dharmasindhu/bookindex.php) book (also hosted at the Kamakoti.org) says the following as regards dreams that are related to snakes:

> Swapna Prakarana: Swimming in a river or Se a, flying in the Sky,
>   Graha-Nakshatra-Surya-Chandra darshana, hiking a high building or a
>   temple, drinking hard drinks, eating meat, spraying krimi-keetaas on
>   one’s body, viewing jewellery and golden articles, drowning in blood
>   streams, eating curd rice, wearing white clothes and applying
>   chandana and such other scented materials; viewing Brahmanas ,
>   Devatas and Kings, viewing women nicely decorated and dresses,
>   encountering a Vrishabha, milk, trees full of attractive fruits;
>   scaling high mountains; obtaining mirrors, meat, flower garlands,
>   whit e flowers and meeting persons dressed in white are all dreams of
>   auspiciousness. On the other hand b ad dreams and their impact include
>   scaling neem, valmeeka and Palasha trees or **snake pits**; obtaining
>   oil, metal and cotton are bad omens. Punarvivaha, Rakta Vastra
>   dharana, drowning in swift currents o f water, eating cooked meat;
>   viewing Grahanaas, droppings of Nakshatras from the Sky are signs of
>   ap proaching signs of death. Seeing the flowers of Ashoka, Karaveera
>   and Palasha is ‘Shoka’or sorrow; a lighting a boat is a sign of
>   travel; wearing blood stained clothes or embracing a woman are signs.
>
> .....
>
> More results of Desirable Dreams are the views of Kings, elephants,
>   horses, Gold, Vrishabha, and scaling of trees would result in monetary
>   gains and Kutumba Vriddhi round the corner. **If there is a dream that
>   white serpent bites a person’s right hand that person would receive a
>   lot of money.** **If a dream occurs that a scorpion or snake devour a
>   person in a water fl ow then that person would soon get victory and
>   excellent progeny**

And, then it repeats, what i have already given, that is the account from the Agni Purana.

Comment: I usually get dreams of falling from above. :(

Comment: Oh that's mentioned among the bad dreams.. Stop reading them i would say.. @Rajas.

Comment: @Rajas What happened to your fb a/c?

Comment: Temporarily deactivated dear @Surya

Comment: @Rickross Sarvam Dukkham Dukkham. :(

Comment: @Rajas Oh okay...

Comment: @Rickross - Ir seems that there is some issue with kamkoti site. I am seeing the error message "Your connection is not private" and link is not working. If that article is mentioning chapter no. etc. let me know ,I will try to add another link as well as sanskrit verses in answer.

Comment: Do you know about dream of bad spirits. I am diong Satya Narayana fasts since long on every purnima. I start fast and followed usual procedure and fell asleep at night. In dream I saw bad spirit in my house disturbing me. Trying to scare me. In normal days I wouldn't care about any kind dreams. But the thing bugged me a lot that why this dream comes during Lord Vishnu's fast. Do you have any idea about this too?

Comment: Ok i will check..must be there.. do u see that dream on every fast nites? @Rishabh

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Yes i too used to see that message few days back..now i don't know how it vanished..probably i did some tweaks or anything or not i don't know.. NO, we can not really know stuffs like exact chapter no.. the book is called essence of Agni Purana.. the next section describes the Papa Nashaka Stotra, so u may get an idea of where to find the verses..

Comment: It happened in my last passed fast only. Don't know if it gonna repeat in upcoming fast of mine too. Purnima is not so far now. Will see.

Comment: Ok @Rishabh as per me Purnima fasts mite not be suitable for u.. Not every fasts are suitable for every person.. for ex- fasting on the 6th Tithis is not good for me.. Also i have discussed earlier with u, that if u fast on Purnima, then the fruits are going not to Vishnu but to Moon God who rules that Tithi. So if u want to fast for Vishnu, then u can do the Ekadashi fasts, which are dedicated to him. And whether Satyanaryan Puja is done on Purnima or not is irrelevant here.

Comment: But Staya Narayana fasts mostly done on Purnima. When I search on google to find next date of fasts then I mostly gets result of purnima date. Although I don't mind switching to ekadashi but mostly people preffer Purnima over Ekadashi. I have seen many people does this fast and all does it on Purnima. Actually there is no fix date of this fast. Satya Narayana kathaa stated we can do this fast on any date. But purnima is most popular for some reason. Besides why u think this fast won't suit me? It is only fast that I know which grants moksha. That's why I decided to do it through out my life.

Comment: To know which fasts are malefic for u, u need to check ur Vedic Kundli. It will have the Ghataka lists. It will give the weekdays (like say friday etc), Tithis, Yogas etc which are malefic for you. So, if u do fast on those days or Tithis, then it mite not turn out fruitful for u. People actually need a good Guru for such purposes only. He will tell u what is good for and what is bad.. Anyways fasting for Vishnu means fasting on Ekadashi. @Rishabh But if u want to do the Satyanaryana vrata only, there is no option for u . You have to fast on Purnimas.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get meaning of this line of your _"But if u want to do the Satyanaryana vrata only, there is no option for u . You have to fast on Purnimas"_. You mean Satyanaryana fasts I have to do on purnima only. But You said earlier it shud be done in Ekadashi. Sorry for my bad understanding but little confuse here.

Comment: @Rishabh I mean this-- although Satyanaryana vrat can be done on any days, but Purnima is preferred.. so if u are doing that particular vrat, then u have to fast on that day i.e Purnima. So, u have no other options. But that day technically belongs to Moon. So, if u really want to please Vishnu by fasting, the most suitable day then is the two Ekadshis per month.

Comment: Okay got your point. Sounds good to me and a valid point. Now onwards I will start fasting on Ekadashi instead (twice a month). Thanks for the clarification and given info :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72160/discussion-between-rishabh-and-rickross).

Comment: What about seeing rain along with rainbow, dissipating clouds and sun in dream?