# When you see snake in your dream?

Tags: superstitions, dream

What is a significance when you see a snake in your dream at night. I see a snake in my dream and I don't remember whether it had one head or several. But it was definitely a cobra because it was in standing position with its hood and massive in size.

Is it a good sign or a bad sign?

Comment: I also use to have such dreams

Comment: There are some questions which ask the same.. Pls search for them..answers mite be already given.. One is here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23662/is-it-a-bad-omen-to-see-snakes-chasing-you-in-dreams

Comment: https://www.astrospeak.com/slides/snakes-in-dream-meaning

Comment: personal advice not allowed on this forum. please see forum rules.