# Do the reason or consequences behind bad dream of killing snake mentioned in scriptures?

Tags: scripture, dream

From [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23663/661) answer, we can notice that dream of killing snake is a bad dream

> Bad dreams are a shaven head of one’s own, wearing shabby clothes,
>   drinking oil, house collapse, angry Gods or Brahmanas, falling from
>   above, **killing snakes** or animals, playing with monkeys, weddings,
>   singing and so on. Prayers to Vishnu, or Shiva or Ganesha or Surya
>   would appease bad dreams, while good dreams should enable the dreamer
>   to make them true if the person discontinues sleeping.

Is there any reason or further consequences for a dream of killing a snake?