# A black lizard or dragon in dream

Tags: meditation, gayatri-mantra, dream

So, I was doing meditation with Gayatri mantra and when I was about to reach 108 I saw a big black lizard or dragon I can't figure it out because it wasn't having a tail. It was slowly climbing a rock. While I was in meditation my body was shaking heavily.
Everything was good but that creature scared me.
Any interpretation on this?

Comment: I see that many questions similar to this has been asked before and accepted, e.g. this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/23662/3881 . Hence not closing this.