# Watching a black snake in dream

Tags: dream

*I saw a dream of **catching a blacksnake in my dream**what does it indicate

*Also I saw **black dog biting my friend and same dog barking at me** what does it indicate

Comment: ulcer on the right side of the lips, tumors, skin cracks, pimples, etc, bad habits indicating - aversion to milk, bathing, morning sleepiness, bad quality of sleep, etc. They could indicate a lot of things at once. Unless regular, there is no harm in dismissing such sort of dreams.

Comment: You might find the following answer useful https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23663/4732