# Sighting of Garuda (Grudha or vulture) when a person is ill. What does it signify?

Tags: belief, animals, garuda, omens

What is the significance of seeing Garuda/Grudha (Vulture) on a tree in front of house ( never appeared in past,
not in the neighborhood too ) and it flew the moment a person looked at it. It appeared as if it wanted him to see it and then it flew Away. Person's family had fell sick day before that sighting.

Keen to know what does this vulture incident signify and its relevance to health of that house/family.

Comment: I will not say “looking for food” possibly and scared by the gaze. The question is what you think it signifies?

Comment: I am not sure that an eagle signifies Garuda? What makes you think that?

Comment: Related: [Is there any significance of flying Eagle touching head?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23622/is-there-any-significance-of-flying-eagle-touching-head)

Comment: Its not Garuda (the mount of Lord Vishnu) but Grudha or vulture.

Answer (score 1):

Chapters [231 and 232](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/12912/6/Chapter4_547-617p.pdf) of Agni Purana have information on omen known from birds.
I see references to hawks and vultures, but nothing on Eagle. So to your question, I am inclined to say it means nothing if an eagle is sighted.

Comment: Sorry for my limited knowledge.  It is vulture and we commonly used to call as eagle and rarely differentiate

Answer (score 1):

It is generally considered a bad omen to have Giddha around you. Twice in Ramayan it is mentioned as bad omen.

Vibhishan lists down flock of Giddha kissing tips of Seven story buildings of Lanka as one of bad omens, which started since Sita was brought to Lanka by Raavan.

> [image: 10th Sarg, Yuddhkand, Valmiki Ramayan]

Valmiki ji lists down Giddha sitting on Kumbhakaran's spear as bad omen.

> [image: 65th Sarg, Yuddhkand, Valmiki Ramayan]