# Do dreams that signify death always come true?

Tags: animals, dream, omens

If someone sees a dream that signify death such as wedding, buffaloes etc. Would that really mean the person is going to die soon. Or it could be just your fear of death?
Edit: [This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23662/is-it-a-bad-omen-to-see-snakes-chasing-you-in-dreams) answer however mentions seeing buffalo is good and [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23260/how-do-you-know-death-is-near-for-a-person-as-per-scriptures-is-there-any-refer?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer doesn't mention about buffalo anywhere.

Comment: Dreams may or may not be true sign of death. Take a real life example, a person had a dream. He asked an famous astrologer to predict it & the person was told that it was the sign of death. Based on his graha & kundali the astrologer even told his fixed date & time of death. After that the person was never seen again. The astrologer thought he's dead. Yet after  a decade of yrs, the same astologer went to Mahakumbha. And to his surprise he saw that same person bathing ritualistically in Ganga. He asked him how couldbhe live. And the person said, when I knew my time was near, I took sharan....

Comment: of my isht, & started rigourous naam jaap. & u see today I'm still alive.        Thus to say, any sign of good or bad or even death appraoching can be nullified with isht kripa. Thus, although dreams **may** be true. But, they can be truly made to turn tables completly. Even wht u told about, the fear of death, true because sometimes we see in dreams what we see outside in the world. Thus just say, "hamare sath shree chandi maat toh, kiss baat ki chinta"  & move on.

Comment: @Chamundadas That's a great example! :)