# What proportion of present day Hindus are aware of Vedanta?

Tags: vedanta, practice

It has been repeated many times at HSE that

> by far the most popular school of Hindu philosophy is the Vedanta school. But there are five other Astika or orthodox schools of Hindu philosophy: Purva Mimamsa, Samkhya, Yoga, Vaisheshika, and Nyaya

It is certainly true that Vedanta has overwhelmingly more mind-share among Hindus than the other five schools mentioned above - but it is still very small.

Hinduism as practiced today consists of temple worship of deities, Puja and Bhajans at home, going to pilgrimage sites, getting Samskaras conducted (most importantly - marriage ceremony and last rites).  Hindus may attend pravachans on the Bhagavad Gita - but it is not presented as Vedanta, as far as I know.

What part does Vedanta play is present day Hinduism as practiced?

this is NOT a duplicate of

[What percentage of Hindus belong to a sect that subscribes to the Vedanta school?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3193/what-percentage-of-hindus-belong-to-a-sect-that-subscribes-to-the-vedanta-school)

The above question is about NOMINAL adherence to one of the six schools and Vedanta is indeed the most popular.

This question asks how many Hindus show awareness of Vedanta in their day-to-day practice of Hinduism.